# Optimal way to handle un-localization of components?

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, localization

Is there a way to trace and get the unlocalized content by accessing the database?

Some of our content got un-localized and we are not able to trace how this could have happened.

To prevent such things in future, can we restrict or put an approval process in place using Workflows, where a group of users will be assigned for any type of un-localizing request?

If the above option is not possible through Workflows, then I am thinking to implement something using event system; where I create a user group and validate the user who is doing un-localization against this group and also logs these details in a log file for traceability.

I am sure this must be a very generic & common problem, hence looking for an optimal approach to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious measure is to ensure that only the right people have the Localize permission. As far as I know, you need this also to unlocalize. And of course, only people with write permission would be able to unlocalize.

You can't use workflow to manage localization, but you certainly could write an events system that enforced your rules. You would want to create an event for:

`Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events.UnLocalizeEventArgs`

If you throw an exception from the Initiated phase, then the unlocalize action will not take place.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But is there a way we can get the lost content back from the database?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - when you unlocalize you lose the changes.

Comment: Well obviously, if you prevent the unlocalize action, there's no need to recover any content.